# Error C2664 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'CHAR [260]' to 'std::wstring'

Tags: c++

im creating a c++ project and i keep getting this error when im building.

Error C2664 '': cannot convert from 'CHAR [260]' to 'std::wstring'

This is my function thats calling

```
uint32_t exe_pid = util::find_process("ProgramName.exe");;
```

and this is the function

```
uint32_t find_process(const std::string& Name) {
    PROCESSENTRY32 ProcessEntry;
    ProcessEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE ProcessSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (Process32First(ProcessSnapshot, &ProcessEntry)) {
        do {
            if (!_stricmp(ws2s(std::wstring(ProcessEntry.szExeFile)).c_str(), Name.data())) {
                CloseHandle(ProcessSnapshot);
                return ProcessEntry.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(ProcessSnapshot, &ProcessEntry));
    }
    CloseHandle(ProcessSnapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the line with the issue

```
 std::wstring(ProcessEntry.szExeFile)
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: C++ strings and Win32 API are a poor match at the best of times. You did not mention the line causing this issue, but I guess it is this `std::wstring(ProcessEntry.szExeFile)`? You need to uncomplicate things and directly compare that with `Name.

Comment: yes thats the correct line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `TCHAR` version of the Win32 API functions, and you are clearly compiling your project with UNICODE turned off, thus:

- `TCHAR` maps to `char`.
- the TCHAR-based `Process32First()` function maps to the ANSI `Process32FirstA()` function.
- the TCHAR-based `Process32Next()` function maps to the ANSI `Process32NextA()` function.
- the TCHAR-based `PROCESSENTRY32` struct maps to the ANSI `PROCESSENTRY32A` struct, and so its `szExeFile` field is a `char[]` array.

`ws2s()` takes a `std::wstring` as input and returns a `std::string`. But `std::wstring` does not have a constructor that accepts a `char[]` as input.  That is why you are getting a compiler error on `std::wstring(ProcessEntry.szExeFile)`.

Since `_stricmp()` takes `const char*` pointers as input, and your input `Name` parameter is a `std::string` <sup>1</sup>, and you are using the ANSI version of the API, you should not be calling `ws2s()` at all.

<sup>1: and as such, you should be using the ANSI version of the API directly, not the TCHAR version.</sup>

Try this instead:

```cpp
uint32_t find_process(const std::string& Name) {
    PROCESSENTRY32A ProcessEntry;
    ProcessEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE ProcessSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (ProcessSnapshot) {
        if (Process32FirstA(ProcessSnapshot, &ProcessEntry)) {
            do {
                if (_stricmp(ProcessEntry.szExeFile, Name.c_str()) == 0) {
                    CloseHandle(ProcessSnapshot);
                    return ProcessEntry.th32ProcessID;
                }
            } while (Process32NextA(ProcessSnapshot, &ProcessEntry));
        }
        CloseHandle(ProcessSnapshot);
    }
    return 0;
}
```